# Issue on sending request through a proxy server

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, httprequest, wininet

I am facing an issue on sending http request using wininet api using when the request is sent through a proxy server.

I have an mfc application which sends a requests to a server.
for sending request is use

```
    HttpSendRequest
```

function of wininet.
I need a file to be uploaded using this. for that 3-4 requst has to be sent related to each file.
When there is a proxy i cant upload more than 3 files at a time.
After that the requests is not sent properly.
Once it is blocked all the requests sent after that doesn't get proper response(some exception occurs).
I have done adding proxy credentials using

```
   InternetSetOption(hConnect, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_USERNAME, (LPVOID)lpUname, nUnameBuffer);
   InternetSetOption(hConnect, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_PASSWORD, (LPVOID)lpPswrd, nPswrdBuffer);
```

when the application is restated then its ok for the next 3 files.
also its working fine if the proxy settings are disabled.

Any one know why this occurres?
is there any limit for request using wininet functions under a proxy?
please help how to solve this issue.
hellpp me plzzzzz

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [MS Support article "How To Handle Proxy Authorization with WinInet"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195650) suggest that you need to respond to `HTTP_STATUS_PROXY_AUTH_REQ` with adding authentication data and re-sending the request.